# Changing my simple JS Array to have key/values instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Im currently using jQuery to build an `Array` like this:

```
var arr = new Array();
   $('#some-form .some-input').each(function() {
   arr.push($(this).val());                                                                                                                    
});
```

which builds something like:

```
arr[0] = 'bar'
arr[1] = 'foo'
```

Now I want a data structure (a 'map'? a JSON array?) to do get something like this:

```
{ 'key1' : 'foo'
  'key2' : 'bar' }
```

because I am now going to store multiple 'things' from `$('#some-form .some-input')`.

In `C`, I think this could be a linked list because you don't know how big the data structure will be in advance so you wouldn't use an array.  However, I AM using an array here which might not be the best idea?  What's sort of structure do I need?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With javascript you can dynamically add properties to an object, so you can do something like this:

```
var arr = {};
$('#some-form .some-input').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    arr[$this.attr('id')] = $this.val();
});
```

And you can access them with `arr.key1; // foo`

Edit: as the comments below note, you can also access the values using the `[]` notation, like `arr['key2'] // bar` (thanks for reminding me :))

Comment: You should add a note that you can also access them with bracket notation

Comment: To be extra clear, In javascript, all objects are essentially just maps.  If you want a map you can just instantiate a new object and use that as your map.  Both dot and [] syntax work for lookup.

Comment: @Laurence that's fine but is it efficient?  You're dynamically adding values and you're dynamically adding keys.. it could be fine but I don't know!  Thanks +1.

Comment: I just found this question which has a very detailed performance run-down you might find useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423493/what-is-the-performance-of-objects-arrays-in-javascript-specifically-for-googl