# How to Send Collection of JS objects to ASP.NET API service?

Tags: javascript, c#, list, asp.net-web-api, collections

I am trying to send collection of JavaScript objects to my API service, But server receive empty object list!

```
<script>

    //Collection
    var Collection = function () {
        this.count = 0;
        this.collection = {};

        this.add = function (key, item) {
            if (this.collection[key] != undefined)
                return undefined;
            this.collection[key] = item;
            return ++this.count
        }
        this.remove = function (key) {
            if (this.collection[key] == undefined)
                return undefined;
            delete this.collection[key]
            return --this.count
        }
        this.item = function (key) {
            return this.collection[key];
        }
        this.forEach = function (block) {
            for (key in this.collection) {
                if (this.collection.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    block(this.collection[key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

// the JavaScript class for food 
  function foodcls(no,qunt,name, cals, carb, fat, prt,unt) {
        this.no = no;
        this.qunt = qunt;
        this.name = name;
        this.cals = cals;
        this.carb = carb;
        this.fat = fat;
        this.prt = prt;
        this.unt = unt;
    }
// instantiate new obj
var fod = new foodcls(3, 5, 'SomeName', 300, 180, 100, 20, 'Gram');
var fno =333;


var timCol = new Collection();
 timCol.add(fno, fod); 

  var urlpaths = '/api/FoodServ';
 $.ajax({
        url: urlpaths, 
        method: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json;  charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(timCol),
        success: function (data) {
// any thing
}
});

</script>
```

Code in ASP.NET API :

```
      [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(List<foodcls> fods) // Here fods is empty
    {
        int rslt=0;
        string UserId = "sam@am.com";//User.Identity.Name;
        List<Foods_Meal_TBL> fooditems = new List<Foods_Meal_TBL>();
          if (fods.Count()>0)
          {
              foreach (foodcls item in fods)
        {
            Foods_Meal_TBL fooditem = new Foods_Meal_TBL();
            fooditem.FoodNo = item.no;
            fooditem.Quantity = item.qunt;
            fooditem.PersonID = UserId;
fooditems.Add(fooditem);
        }
         }
        rslt = SaveAllItems(fooditems); // rslt Meal No
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, rslt);
    }
```

Any help please ?

Comment: Just send the items in array. Try to do that. and see how it hits it.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the XHR object from the AJAX call, change your sucess object to : success:function(data, status, xhr){/*break here or use alert */
alert(xhr.responseText);}.....

Comment: @Casey it worked with array but I need it in Collection, so I can reach it by key

Comment: @nixxbb Thanks, But I made a breakpoint on asp.net api post function to check the data first, The AJAX call reach the asp.net function but not send the data!

Comment: Not sure about Collections and JSON formatting, I always create objects var obj = {key:val} and add them to an array. Then I recall having some troubles parsing the JSON into a List, but it's been a while and I guess I'm not as familiar with what you are doing as I thought, sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found away to solve the issue by convert the collection to array, I know it is not the best solution, And I hope someone could find better solution that avoid use array, but until someone give a better answer, I put my way to fix that as below:
I have added the function  toArr  // means covert collection to array as below:

```
//Collection
var Collection = function () {
this.count = 0;
this.collection = {};

this.add = function (key, item) {
    if (this.collection[key] != undefined)
        return undefined;
    this.collection[key] = item;
    return ++this.count
}
this.remove = function (key) {
    if (this.collection[key] == undefined)
        return undefined;
    delete this.collection[key]
    return --this.count
}
this.item = function (key) {
    return this.collection[key];
}
this.forEach = function (block) {
    for (key in this.collection) {
        if (this.collection.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            block(this.collection[key]);
        }
    }
}
this.toArr = function (block) {   //ToArray
    var fodarr = [];
    for (key in this.collection) {
        if (this.collection.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            fodarr.push(this.collection[key]);// block(this.collection[key]);
        }
    }
    return fodarr;
}
```

}

ASP.NET API function :

```
  [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Post(foodcls[] fods)
```

Hope that help someone in future...

Answer (score 1):

You can add method inside your Collection for converting you local collection to JSON object.

```
var Collection = function () {
        this.count = 0;
        this.collection = {};

        this.add = function (key, item) {
            if (this.collection[key] != undefined)
                return undefined;
            this.collection[key] = item;
            return ++this.count
        }
        this.remove = function (key) {
            if (this.collection[key] == undefined)
                return undefined;
            delete this.collection[key]
            return --this.count
        }
        this.item = function (key) {
            return this.collection[key];
        }
        this.toJSON = function(){
            return JSON.stringify(this.collection);
        }
        this.forEach = function (block) {
            for (key in this.collection) {
                if (this.collection.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    block(this.collection[key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope, it will help. Also suggestion: do not use objects for storing values, because they are [slower then arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8584173/3245626).