# send a collection of documents from the VIEW(controller AngularJS) to the CONTROLLER in ASP.net MVC

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, collections, document

I am working with MongoDB (non-relational database) I try to send a collection with two documents, I fill the collection very well but at the time of sending it arrives without the documents..

***CONTROLLER ANGULARJS--------------------------------------------------------------------***
[image]

***CONTROLLER-----------------------------------------------***

[image]

***MODELs-----------------------------------------------***

[image]
[image]
[image]

[I tryed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32867074/how-to-send-collection-of-js-objects-to-asp-net-api-service)