# Javascript and function complexity

Tags: javascript, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I was wondering what are the complexity (in big O notation) of certain functions of some prototypes (in best AND worst case) in Javascript ? I can't find any document listing these informations concerning :

- Object.assign

EDIT : All the previous cases are covered in (except Object.assign) [What is the performance of Objects/Arrays in JavaScript? (specifically for Google V8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423493/what-is-the-performance-of-objects-arrays-in-javascript-specifically-for-googl)

Can you help me ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the performance of Objects/Arrays in JavaScript? (specifically for Google V8)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423493/what-is-the-performance-of-objects-arrays-in-javascript-specifically-for-googl)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this way, I just need to know what is the complexity of Object.assign :-)

Comment: Object.assign is O(N) :)

Comment: Thanks for this, I m closing the topic so :). Pass it into answer, so I can upvote your answer :D

Comment: I guess the post would be better if i post an argumentation ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Object.assign is basically looping an array once and assigning the value to the object, I think it's safe to say the complexity is O(n).

Check out the polyfill version here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

It DOES show a nested loop, but since only one of the loops is linked to the length of the argument passed, the notation is still O(x*n) => O(n)